# How to allow a user to scale imageviews and retain photo quality?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to figure out a solution that best allows the user to resize an image (live with a pinch gesture) as well as retain as much quality as possible.

My app basically shows a few imageViews scaled down in size when `viewDidLoad` runs. I'm using [UIImage+Resize](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) as a way of scaling them down and keeping quality.

I'm using a pinch gesture to affect the `CGAffineTransformScale` to let the user increase/decrease the photo size. Now, the issue is `CGAffineTransformScale` doesn't do anything for image quality. It will simply stretch out the image.

Is there a way to make the photo quality increase WHILE increasing the imageview frame size? I suppose I could simply access the original image, and replace the imageView.image with a new image based on the dimensions when `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. However it looks pretty ugly when the photo is being scaled during the pinch phase.

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CATiledLayer? [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html)
is some sample code from Apple.